# Can't install Eclipse IDE for Java, is there any better suggestion for Java IDE in 16.10?

Tags: software-installation, software-recommendation, eclipse, 16.10, maven-3

Is there any Java IDE with Maven support on Ubuntu 16.10?

Answer (score 1):

NetBeans IDE from the default Ubuntu 16.10 repositories supports the Maven build system. Open, build, run, debug, profile, and deploy your existing Maven projects, which can be opened without an import procedure.

NetBeans and IntelliJ don't need a plugin for Maven support, but IntelliJ is not in the default Ubuntu 16.10 repositories .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I second the Netbeans suggestion. I actually use it for C++ on Linux, it's great! If the one in the repositories is out of date, you can download a linux installer .sh script from the Netbeans site.
https://netbeans.org/downloads/