# Work on a Java Project in Ubuntu

Tags: java, jdk, github, jre, atom

I am a beginner so I apologize if you're gonna read a silly question.

I want to work on a Java Project. It's a project available on GitHub: https://github.com/particleincell/Starfish.

The problem is that I feel quite lost about how to actually work on it. 
I didn't understand very well the various components needed to program in java (JRE, JDK etc).
I cloned the project on my PC and managed to get it to work from the terminal. However in the future I will need to implement plugins (working on the source code) and I would like to understand what could be the best way to do it.
Atom seems to be a valid editor but I did not understand if it is enough to work on a Java project and how to work on it. 
I really need help getting started.
For now I have always done it myself but every time there was some problem that I could solve from the beginning if I set everything well.
This time I have a lot more time and I would like to start off properly to work as a real programmer.

Thank you very much!

Tommaso

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install Eclipse IDE for Java, is there any better suggestion for Java IDE in 16.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837943/cant-install-eclipse-ide-for-java-is-there-any-better-suggestion-for-java-ide)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JRE only allows you to execute Java programs.

The JDK contains the necessary components to compile java source code and create executable code (that will require a JRE to run). It usually includes the corresponding JRE.

An IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ) contains an editor with a lot of additional functionality (on-the-fly syntax checking, code completion, debugger, Git interface...). It is the recommended way to work on a Java project.